# Good Will Hunting Follow Up Question

Tags: finite-groups

I recently asked a question from the movie Good Will Hunting. Here is a link [Good Will Hunting Problem Reasoning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941664/good-will-hunting-problem-reasoning/1941702#1941702) if you want more information.  The matrix T is equal to 
the scalar z times the matrix shown below. I found the correct generating function for walks i to j which is S. 
[image]

\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 2 & 1\\ 0 & 2 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}

How do we know [image] 
                               converges to zero?

Comment: How do you define "$T^{\infty+1}$?"

Comment: If you meant to ask, "for what values of $z$ does $Az$ (where $A$ is the adjacency matrix) converge," the answer is $z=0$. We instead consider the generating function $\sum_{n=0}^\infty A^nz^n$ as an element of the ring of formal power series with real coefficients, which has the unique inverse $I-Az$.